# MX records dual mail servers

Tags: email-server, mx-record

My company uses google suite for most of the emails, i recently migrated the server to a vps however all my mx records point to google

when i add a mx record to the local vps the other email at the gmail servers fail when i remove or lower the priority of the mx record for the vps then the local email fails to receive

Question: how can i send to both servers each server has different emails some are on the gmail servers some are on the local vps

```
MX (mydomain)  mail handled by alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 20
MX (mydomain)  mail handled by alt2.aspmx.l.google.com 30   
MX (mydomain)  mail handled by aspmx2.googlemail.com 40 
MX (mydomain)  mail handled by aspmx3.googlemail.com 50
MX (mydomain)  mail handled by aspmx.l.google.com 10
```

when i try to add

```
MX (mydomain)  mail handled by (mydomain) domain.com 1
```

the google hosted email accounts fail as no user 
when i set it to priority 60 the local vps email accounts fail as no user

```
MX (mydomain)  mail handled by (mydomain) 60
```

so how can i have the google accounts goto google server and the local vps accounts come to local vps server

Answer (score 3):

The MX records for your domain need to point to **either** Google **or** your server. Not both.

My recommendation would be to keep your MX records pointing at Google, and then configure [split delivery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2685650) email routing there, to fork off some recipients to your self-managed server. Here's what Google has to say about split delivery (taken from the above-linked page):

> With split delivery, an incoming message is delivered to either a
>   Gmail inbox or a legacy system inbox, depending on the recipient.
>
> This method works well if some of your users use Gmail, and others use
>   a different mail system. For example, you might need to implement
>   special handling for certain types of email, such as messages to the
>   Legal department.